# for loop cell contents into new cell X amount of times vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column that contains 50 rows of text. I want to copy each cell and paste its value in a different column, but do so X amount of times based on a separate input. My mind defaults to thinking pythonically, and I want to append each item to a list for manipulation, though I don't think that is necessary in this instance.

```
Sub fipsloop()

finalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row

p = Worksheets("StateSource").Range("B3:").Select
p_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(p)

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
rng = Range("e3:finalRow")

For Each cell In rng
    If x.Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    If p_count > 1 Then

    '# here is where I am stuck. 

Next cell
```

"p_count" is the number of times I want to paste each cell's contents into a different column. So if there are 50 items in column E, and my "p_count" variable is 2, then I will paste each item twice and will have 100 items in my new column.

In python I would append each item X amount of times to a list. Is there a way to do something like that within VBA?

Comment: like the adverb `pythonically`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the .Value property in your loop.  This will copy the value from column 5/E into  cells in column 16/P very quickly:

```
For rowIndex = 1 to p_count
    Worksheets("StateSource").cells(rowIndex, 16).Value = Worksheets("StateSource").cells(rowIndex, 5).Value
Next
```

Comment: What do you mean by " your value here"? and is your suggestion going under the "if" statement inside the for loop, or is that in lieu of it?

Comment: Your formula goes in there, it could be as simple as "=A1+B1".  I'm not really sure what your if statement is doing other than checking for blank values, but it's really up to you.

Comment: My values are in 'E' and I want to copy their value (X amount of times aka p_count) to 'P'

Comment: Updated to reflect this.